# How do I make sure that my extension’s observer is called last of all observers registered for the same event?

Tags: event-observer

Each extension can add observers, so one can end up with multiple <observers> for the same <event>.

Sometimes I need to be sure that all essential data is initialised when my observer function kicks in. So I want my observer to be called last of the bunch.

Or sometimes I want it to be first, or at least before core's observer, so that all the data important to me is there before the core observer saves it.

Can I influence the order in which observer functions for the same event are executed?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934553/how-do-you-set-the-sort-order-for-event-observers-in-magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possibility to achieve this by declaring *Module Dependency<sup>**1**</sup>* in your extension. Below I will show you the two cases which will help you to ORDER your observer in effective way.

### Scenario

Let us call our module `Namespace_Module`. Suppose you are observing to an event `some_example_event_to_observe`. Now suppose below modules are also observing the same event.

- Mage_Cms
- Mage_Customer
- Namespace_Module
- SomeNamespace_SomeModule
- SomeOtherComapny_SomeOtherModule

*Please note, without any module dependency, Magento is going observe the event in the same listed order*

### Case - I

You want your module observer should trigger only after observer of `SomeNamespace_SomeModule`. For that case, your activation file will look like this.

```
File: app\etc\modules\Namespace_Module.xml
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <SomeNamespace_SomeModule />
            </depends>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

See the `<depend />` tag. We just specified there that, our module depends on `SomeNamespace_SomeModule`. Therefore Magento will process observer `SomeNamespace_SomeModule` first and then consider our observer.

### Case - II

We want our observer to listen at last. In this case, our module's activation file will look like

```
File: app\etc\modules\Namespace_Module.xml
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <SomeNamespace_SomeModule />
                <SomeOtherComapny_SomeOtherModule />
            </depends>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Since we specified our module now depends on `SomeNamespace_SomeModule` and `SomeOtherComapny_SomeOtherModule`, our module is going to load last.

### Case - III

We need to trigger our event very first. In that case

```
File: app\etc\modules\Namespace_Module.xml
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Namespace_Module>
        <Mage_Cms>
            <depends>Namespace_Module</depends>
        </Mage_Cms>
        <Mage_Customer>
            <depends>Namespace_Module</depends>
        </Mage_Customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here we make our module as a dependency for the core modules `Mage_Cms` and `Mage_Customer`. This will force our module's observer to listen very first.

I hope this will make sense now. Let me know if you have any further doubts.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> : ***Module dependency*** is a technique which is used in Magento for *ordering loading of modules* based on the dependency specified in the activation files (XML files which we can find inside `app/etc/modules/`)

Comment: Modules are loaded alphabetically, so you can also influence the load and execution order by renaming a module so that it is loaded before another.

Comment: @paj true. But in almost all cases renaming an extension will be a bitter experience. So I strongly oppose that "trick". I feel it is bad.